# Wifi goes off on screen lock?

Tags: wi-fi, lock-screens

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I keep my wi-fi on in sleep mode](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/16/how-do-i-keep-my-wi-fi-on-in-sleep-mode)

It seems to me that the wifi on my phone goes off when the screen gets locked. That way it's not syncing and I don't get notifications. Can this be changed so that it stays on all the time except when you manualy turn it off?

(htc hero, android2.2)

thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/16/how-do-i-keep-my-wi-fi-on-in-sleep-mode

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  `Settings -> Wireless and network -> WiFi settings -> (menu button) Advanced -> Wifi sleep policy -> Never`