# Turn off Wi-Fi Power Saving?

Tags: wi-fi, battery-life

Is there a way to turn off wi-fi power saving mode on Android, i.e. have the wi-fi radio stay on at all times?  I'd rather have a stable, low-latency wi-fi connection and slightly less battery life than a flaky wi-fi connection and longer battery life.  In other words I'd like to enable constant active mode for my wi-fi.

EDIT:  To clarify, I'm talking about the millisecond time scale power saving mode that's part of the wi-fi standard.  This is where the radio wakes up on every beacon, not the minute time scale power saving where wi-fi is disabled completely.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by power saving? Are you referring to when your screen is off (the wifi "sleep policy")? You may want to look at [How do I keep my wi-fi on in sleep mode](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/16/how-do-i-keep-my-wi-fi-on-in-sleep-mode)

Answer (score 6):

Settings -> Wireless and network -> Wi-Fi settings -> (Menu) Advanced -> Wi-Fi sleep policy -> Never.