# How do I set Wi-Fi sleep policy to Never on Froyo 2.2 Droid X without Advanced Wi-Fi Settings menu?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, wi-fi, settings, battery-life

I've encountered the following instructions on a [forum](https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!category-topic/maps/google-maps-for-mobile/T1bA66-S9hM) about battery drain

> Set Wi-Fi sleep to Never in the `Settings > Wireless & Networks > Wi-Fi Settings > Advanced >Wi-Fi Sleep Policy` menu.

However, my Droid X (Stock rooted Froyo 2.2) doesn't have "Advanced" option in "Wi-Fi Settings" menu!

**How do I set Wi-Fi Sleep Policy?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I keep my wi-fi on in sleep mode](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/16/how-do-i-keep-my-wi-fi-on-in-sleep-mode)

Comment: Not a duplicate. The answer to that question mentions an "Advanced" option, which the OP says is missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those instructions sound incomplete. You need to press the `Menu` button on the Wi-Fi Settings screen. `Advanced` will be in the menu.