# Fail to connect to ADB Wifi when device goes to idle state?

Tags: wi-fi, adb, wakelock

I am connecting to my Android phone with ADB WiFi (no USB plugged in). However, whenever my device goes to sleep, I am losing connection and unable to reconnect.

In what I am trying to do, I need to have the screen off. And this is why I am using wake lock to keep CPU awake while device is idling. However, even with wake lock and wifi lock, I am still having the same problem.

Does anyone know how can I connect to ADB over wifi in this situation? or connect while screen is off?

Comment: My only other option would be to physically disconnect the screen.

Comment: have you looked through the other questions we've got on here about people who are having problems keeping the wifi on when the screen turns off? Eg [How do I keep my wi-fi on in sleep mode](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/16/), or [My Samsung Galaxy Ace disconnects from Wi-Fi when sleeping even after setting the Wi-Fi sleep policy](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19503/) and the linked questions from those. It may also be that this is a problem with the OS version or drivers on your device, so editing your question to include your device and OS version would be helpful.